# Cmd windows >> log.bat

Tags: windows, cmd, subroutine

I'm trying to send the subroutine command with which it will subroutine that will create a log!

version of my code

```
echo echo del %%file%% >subroutine.bat >temp.bat
```

this part "echo del %file% >subroutine.bat" to be stored in the subroutine

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `echo del %%file%% >subroutine.bat` to be stored in a file `temp.bat` then

```
echo echo del %%file%% ^>subroutine.bat >temp.bat
```

will do the job. The caret (`^`) turns off the special meaning of the redirector `>` so that it is echoed literally. You can do this with any character having a special meaning to `cmd` `&^!<>|` **except** `%`. To `echo` a `%` you need to double the `%` thus: `echo %%`